# Limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\cdot \sin((-1)^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Why does the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\cdot \cos((-1)^n)$ is $+\infty$?

And if it was limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\cdot \sin((-1)^n)$ ?

This is what I think has no limit.

Comment: It exists if you accept divergence to $+\infty$ as existence

Comment: P.S. use backslashes in MathJax! e.g. `\cos` will do the obvious thing... much better than `cos`. The difference: $\cos$ vs. $cos$

Comment: Sorry, but $\cos(-1)^n=\cos1>0$, so the limit is $+\infty$ most definitely.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking $n\cdot \sin(-1)^n$.

Comment: Hint: $n\sin(-1)^n=(-1)^nn\sin1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since cosine is an even function, we have $\cos(-1)^n=\cos 1$ for all $n$.

Then the difference of two consecutive terms is $(n+1)\cos 1-n\cos 1=\cos 1$. By putting $\epsilon=\cos 1$, the original sequence is not Cauchy, hence not convergent at all.